# How to block random-named browser page elements with specific name parts with uBlock Origin?

Tags: ublock-origin

For example, we have a Twitch Video wrapper, that has it's div name in the body randomised, but the it always has the word `wrapper` in it before the randomised gibberish.

How do I make a script for uBlock Origin to remove all such elements from the page, before they load? I sorta read about selectors, but still barely have a clue.

Examples:

```
<div id="wrapperlUmwRKhPnfuBkJgOHxSqrcWiIY"style="margin: 0 auto; text-align: center;">
<div id="wrapperQEdoiJHFGHgHFfHJuYiyuiGhjh"style="margin: 0 auto; text-align: center;">
```

Comment: This should work as far as selectors go: `div[id^="wrapper"]`. But personally am unfamiliar with how uBlock Origin works so not too sure what the next steps would be.